# Is it possible to import wav files using filedialog in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a wav file player, and I have 'play' and 'choose' buttons

you choose the wav you want to play
then you press the play button and it should play.

instead it just plays an error sound, but ide shows no errors.

So this is probably because it's not getting the wav file you decided to choose from the file dialog.

How do I make filedialog actually import the wav, or am I doing something wrong all together?

Code:

```
#IMPORTS
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from threading import Timer
import winsound
import time
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from playsound import playsound
from colorama import Fore
import os
import time
from tkinter import filedialog
#IMPORTS


def choosethemusic():
    global selected
    #THIS OPENS THE FILE DIALOG!
    selected = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="D:/", title='Choose Your WAV', filetypes=
    (("wav files", "*.wav"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    #THIS OPENS THE FILE DIALOG!

    print('Music Mounted')



playing = True



def playthemusic():
    global selected

    pausebutton.place_forget()
    playbutton.place(x=150, y=60, )
    if playing == True:


        #THIS SHOULD PLAY THE WAV THAT'S SELECTED!
        winsound.PlaySound(str(selected), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        #THIS SHOULD PLAY THE WAV THAT'S SELECTED!



        playbutton.place_forget()
        pausebutton.place(x=150, y=60, )
    if selected == False:
        print('Playing Nothing')
    elif selected == True:
        print('Playing Music!')


def pausethemusic():
    pausebutton.place_forget()
    playbutton.place(x=150, y=60, )
    playing = False
    if playing == False:
        winsound.PlaySound('bin/nuthing.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)



playbuttonIMG = ImageTk.PhotoImage((Image.open("bin/playbuttonimg.png")))
playbutton = Button(root, image=playbuttonIMG, command=playthemusic)
playbutton.place(x=150, y=60,)




pausebuttonIMG = ImageTk.PhotoImage((Image.open("bin/pausebuttonimg.png")))
pausebutton = Button(root, image=pausebuttonIMG, command=pausethemusic)

choosebuttonIMG = ImageTk.PhotoImage((Image.open("bin/choosebuttonimg.png")))
choosebutton = Button(root, image=choosebuttonIMG, command=choosethemusic)

choosebutton.place(x=200, y=60,)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `askopenfile()` returns a open file object, not the filename.  Use `askopenfilename()`.

Comment: @acw1668 you the greatest of all time, ty